# Google drive and one drive sign in gives internet connection errors

Tags: onedrive

I have downloaded google drive and after its installation when google drive icon pops out for sign in, it gives me internet connection error. however my internet connection is working fine. i have tried it multiple times but failed. Same was the case with one drive sign in. Is there any problem with my connection settings? help me please

[image: sign-in error]

Comment: Do you use proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: yes, thank you so much. there was proxy settings activated.I have have just changed it to default settings and it worked fine. :) Thanks bro

Comment: please,  mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: If you got the solution for your problem you should [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) any of the following answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your system uses PROXY to connect to the internet.
Try to change the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to completely quit out of Google Drive and restarting the application. If that doesn't work, then reinstall Google Drive.